# Is this possible to generate self expiring download link in C# - WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, download

I'm working on a C# - WPF project like Zune and want to sell some digital goods like apps by it so I want to create a disposable link to the files in my server and After successful payment in my application, generate a new download link for the requested file. Also this link should expire after it is downloaded.

Is this possible to do? if yes how can i do it?

Comment: Yes of course this is possible. You would need to create a Content Mangement System. You would need to before the file is downloaded determine if the user is still authorized to download the file.  You need to ask a specfic question.  This question `as-is` is really broad.

Comment: but how generate download link after authorize user?

Comment: That would be up to your Content Mangement System.  There isn't a way that your web server will known "without a doubt" the file was actually downloaded.  This is the reason I would use a system to verify the user was authorize to request and download the file instead.

Comment: You might have a look at the Amazon S3 API for some inspiration, it is capable of most of what you require, and has plenty of documentation surrounding its implementation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sir or Ma'am,

I think your design is a bit wrong.  You said you’re working on a Zune'esk project.  That means that you should be able to forego the use of links and use web services like WCF or SOAP.  Change your design and make your WPF project call the web service.  Then once your app download the content, let it call back to the API and mark the item downloaded in your persistency store and call it a day.  You can also set a “Issued” date time stamp on your token that expires in 1 day.  This way if the user never comes back for the item, it will auto-expire.

Once you get this working, then you can go ahead and add authentication and validation structure that ensures one user to a download.  There are many authentication frameworks to choose from like Windows, username/password, ect.